# AJAX post performs action but returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, http-status-code-403

In a Laravel project, I am making AJAX requests like below. It has worked on a lot of different computers and different networks, but for a specific company, it doesn't.

The requests are actually performed as they should, BUT they return 403 Forbidden. The "only problem" is therefore the error code. If they would just return with a success message, everything would be great.

Any suggestions on what's wrong? Can I do something do fix it, or does the customer maybe need to open up for something? They have told me, that they have a high level of security, but I can't see why their security should block this, when it actually performs the actions.

Alternatively, if I can do something hacky to just ignore the 403 (but still handle other error codes) and continue to 'done', it would be great tempoary.

```
// General AJAX header
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

// Request
var formData = new FormData(curr[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    url: '/company/teams',
    data: formData,
    processData: false
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    // Errors
})
.done(function(data) {
    // Success
});
```

Comment: have you defined default document for directories? Does `/company/teams` points to `/company/teams/index.php` or something similar?

Comment: Need to find out why it is forbidden. That is typically an authorization issue. Ignoring it wouldn't make much sense

Comment: It's all handled by Laravels routing - how it works beneath, I don't know. But it acceses the controller function correctly and performs it - instead of returning a success message, it gives a 403 - but only for one company.

Comment: This looks like a .htaccess issue to me. Are any other routes working as expected?

Comment: Everything works as expected - even here. The only problem is, that it returns a 403 Forbidden, even though the actions doesn't get blocked - it is actually performed. And it is only for one particular company, that the problem occurs.

Comment: Can you post your controller code for that route?

Comment: It's not for one specific route - it's the same for all AJAX post requests. Works pretty much everywhere, but on this specific company's network, the requests returns 403, even though the requests are performed.